# Clang tidy: adds paranthesis at end of expression

Tags: c++, clang, clang-tidy

I'm trying to write a clang tidy matcher that replaces the usage of a given macro within the call of a function. Let's make an example to better explain my case.

```cpp
#define ADD(a, b) \
    (a + b)

int foo(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}

int add(int a, int b, int c) {
    return a + b + c;
}
```

Needed replacement:

```cpp
foo(1, ADD(2, 3), 4);
```

into

```cpp
foo(1, add(2, 3, 4));
```

For matching the `ADD` macro I defined a class that inherits from `PPCallbacks` and I override the method `MacroExpands` to get the list of the arguments and make the replacement with the function `add`.

```cpp
static bool isAdd_Macro(StringRef MacroName) {
  static const llvm::StringSet<> MacroNames = {"ADD"};

  return MacroNames.find(MacroName) != MacroNames.end();
}

class ReplaceMacroCallback : public PPCallbacks {
public:
  ReplaceMacroCallback(ReplaceMacro *Check, Preprocessor *PP) : Check(Check), PP(PP) {}

  void MacroExpands(const Token &MacroNameTok, const MacroDefinition &MD, SourceRange Range, const MacroArgs *Args) override {
    IdentifierInfo *NameIdentifierInfo = MacroNameTok.getIdentifierInfo();
    if (!NameIdentifierInfo)
      return;

    auto MacroName = NameIdentifierInfo->getName();

    if (!isAdd_Macro(MacroName) || !Args || Args->getNumMacroArguments() != 2) {
      return;
    }

    SourceRange LocationToBeReplaced(Range.getBegin(), Range.getEnd());

    const auto *FirstArgToken = Args->getUnexpArgument(0);
    const auto *SecondArgToken= Args->getUnexpArgument(1);
    if (!FirstArgToken || !SecondArgToken) {
      return;
    }

    auto FirstArg = PP->getSpelling(*FirstArgToken);
    auto SecondArg = PP->getSpelling(*SecondArgToken);

    std::ostringstream CodeReplacement;
    CodeReplacement << "add(" << FirstArg << ", " << SecondArg;

    Check->diag(Range.getBegin(), "Replace \"%0\" with add")
      << MacroName << FixItHint::CreateReplacement(LocationToBeReplaced, CodeReplacement.str());
  }

private:
  ReplaceMacro *Check;
  Preprocessor *PP;
};
```

So far, everything is clear. Now the problem that I'm trying to solve, is how to add the close parenthesis of `add` at the end of the expression.

```cpp
foo(1, add(2, 3, 4));
                  ^
```

Does somebody have an idea how to do that?